# Implemented a sidebar based on user with most posts and comments

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i want to implement a sidebar based on user with most posts and comments in laravel 5.2 app, 
i want to show the top 5 users with most posts and comment.
Exemple Like this: 
User Name: "Mohcin", Post:30, answer:20
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Open `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`
2. In this file you have an empty (probably) `boot` method.
3. Inside this method, you can create a **view composer** to pass data for a specific view.

Like this:

```
//Assuming you want to pass the var to the view: sidebar.blade.php inside resources/views/layout
view()->composer('layout.sidebar', function($view){
    $topUsers = User::topUsers(); //Create a query or scope to do this...
    //After populate topUsers, you have to pass it to the view using:
    $view->with('topUsers', $topUsers);
});
```

In your view: `resources/views/layout/sidebar.blade.php, you can access the users with a simple $topUsers like this:

```
foreach($topUsers as $user) {
    var_dump($user);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, no i want to desplay the first 5 top users with most posts like this:
User1 (5 Posts)
User5 (3 Posts)
User2 (2 Posts)
....

Comment: You can do whatever you want there. Like this:
    $post = \App\User::your-query-to-get-users-with-posts();

Comment: In app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php. You can pass the vars to the view using the `with` method. In the view you can access as usual. For example: if you use $view->with('topUsers', $users); you can use the var $topUsers

Comment: i'm beginner at laravel can you explain, step by step..
Where i can put the query and how i can show the result in sidebar?

Comment: Can you give me an query exemple, based on user with most high posts.
And thank you verrrrrry much

Comment: I will comment user and post(qiestion) model now

Comment: I need to see the questions table fields too

Comment: id int(10) 

 2 user_id int(10)  
 3 question text 
 

 4 solved tinyint(1)

 5 image varchar(255) 
    
 6 created_at timestamp   
 7 updated_at timestamp 
 8 category_id int(10)

Comment: Try: $users = User::leftJoin('questions','user.id','=','questions.user_id')->
               selectRaw('user.*, count(questions.user_id) AS `total`')->
               groupBy('users.id')->
               orderBy('total','DESC')->
               skip(0)->take(5)->get();

Comment: Remove spaces between arrows (`->`) and methods: from this `-> selectRaw` to `->selectRaw`

Comment: I do this but still the some probleme: view()->composer('questions.side', function($view){
 $users = User::leftJoin('questions','user.id','=','questions.user_id'‌​)->selectRaw('user.*, count(questions.user_id) AS total')->groupBy('users.id')->orderBy('total','DESC')->skip(0)->take(5)->get(); 
//After populate topUsers, you have to pass it to the view using:
$view->with('users', $users);
 }

Comment: I updated my answer. It was not closing the `composer` parenthesis. You should have: view()->composer('questions.side', function($view){ $users = User::leftJoin('questions','user.id','=','questions.user_id'‌​‌​)->selectRaw('user‌​.*, count(questions.user_id) AS total')->groupBy('users.id')->orderBy('total','DESC')->skip(‌​0)->take(5)->get(); //After populate topUsers, you have to pass it to the view using: $view->with('users', $users); });

Comment: I update it but still the some probleme: FatalErrorException in AppServiceProvider.php line 15: syntax error, unexpected '‌​‌​‌​' (T_STRING)

Comment: public function boot()
 {
  //
  view()->composer('questions.side', function($view){ $users = User::leftJoin('questions','user.id','=','questions.user_id'‌​‌​‌​)->selectRaw('us‌​er‌​.*, count(questions.user_id) AS total')->groupBy('users.id')->orderBy('total','DESC')->skip(‌​‌​0)->take(5)->get()‌​; //After populate topUsers, you have to pass it to the view using: 
   $view->with('users', $users); });

public function register()
 {
  $this->app->bind(
   'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar',
   'App\Services\Registrar'
  );
 }

Comment: I'm not understand you ?

Comment: Update your question with the `AppServiceProvider` code

Comment: :( still : syntax error, unexpected '‌​‌​‌​‌​' (T_STRING)

Comment: I understand, but i need you to show me your `AppServiceProvider` code. Not in a comment because it doesn't format properly.

Comment: Can you give me your twitter or facebook if you can.?

Comment: twitter is @pinhojoaoffc

Comment: i followed you can you follow back to talk .. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

User model:

```
use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];


    public function questions(){

        return $this->hasMany('\App\Question');
    }


    public function answers(){

        return $this->hasMany('\App\Answer');
    }
```

Question model: (posts model)

```
 public function User(){

  return $this->belongsTo('\App\User');

}


public function answers(){

        return $this->hasMany('\App\Answer');

}

public static function your_questions(){


    return static::where ('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)->paginate(50);
}
public static function unsolved(){


    return static::where ('solved','=',0)->orderby('id','DESC')->latest()->paginate(50);
}
public static function unsolvedbar(){


    return static::where ('solved','=',0)->orderby('id','DESC')->latest()->take(3)->get();;
}


public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}

public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
}
```